# Printing more results from MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, select, extract

I need to extract records from a database like this:

```
id
name
request1
request2
request3
request4
request5
time
```

request fields can be 0 or 1

and I have my SQL query `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC` but I'm getting only one record for row, but I need to print the records like this:

```
id1 - name1 - request1
id1 - name1 - request2
id2 - name2 - request4
id2 - name2 - request5
```

this means having an extract for every single "`request = 1`"

How can I afford this?

```
require("datisql.php");
dbconnect();
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");  

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM richieste ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $id="{$row['id']}";
    $nominativo="{$row['nominativo']}";
    $data="{$row['timestamp']}";
    echo"<div>...........";
}
```

Here an abstract of the requests table: [click me](http://s30.postimg.org/baw468sht/Schermata_2015_04_21_alle_03_55_12.jpg)

Comment: Are you looping the fetch? Could you please post your code?

Comment: Sure Chris!  
require("datisql.php");
dbconnect();
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");  
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM richieste ORDER BY id DESC");
 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 ) )
    {
    
    $id="{$row['id']}";
    $nominativo="{$row['nominativo']}";
    $data="{$row['timestamp']}";
    
     
    
    echo"<div>..........." 

Tnx a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you edit your question so the code goes in there and can be more easily read?

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to do it :) (Sorry for beeing a newbie)

Comment: I added the code in the question, hope that's the right way to do it

Comment: Your only setting the data once. How many `div`s do you get?

Comment: do nominativo and timestamp exist as column name in your db table?

Comment: yes, they do exist.

Here an abstract of the "requests" table: [link]http://s30.postimg.org/baw468sht/Schermata_2015_04_21_alle_03_55_12.jpg[/link]

Comment: How many divs do you get, 3 or 1?... or where are you using `$id` etc.

Comment: I get one div for every Database ROW, while I should need One div for every requests per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that all of the requests columns are in one row. If I am wrong, I will change that. The way I would handle taking a recordset that looks like that would be to loop through each row and throw each row into a for loop like this:

```
// Add each of the request types to an array
$requestTypes = array('Interior','Exterior');

// Loop through the resultset
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 ) ){
    foreach($requestTypes as $type){
        $id= $row['id'];
        $nominativo = $row['nominativo'];
        $requestedType = $row[$type];
        $data = $row['timestamp'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already in a loop. `while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 ) ) {`

Comment: @Cody Christofferson tnx for your answer! You are right, all the requests columns are in a row but each "request" has a different name, for example: "Interior", "Exterior", "etc."

Comment: chris85, I answered this question as he was adding his code. When I wrote it out, there was no supporting code above.

Comment: Matteo, ok, that complicates things a little, but not significantly. Modifying my answer.

Comment: @CodyChristofferson tnx a lot!

Comment: I changed it a little to correlate with your question above.

Comment: @CodyChristofferson Tnx Again! It seems a great solution! I think you really gave me the right answer! :)